# jQuery loop through JSON with one key

Tags: jquery, json

I have JSON with following values:

```
key1 : value1, value2, value3
key2 : othervalue1, othervalue2, othervalue3
```

I need to loop only through one key, for example key1, so
I tried this:

```
for(var i in data){
    console.log(data.key1);
}
```

But instead getting one value in each row:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

I get: `value1,value2,value3`

I hope you understand

Comment: can you add your JSON too, `"key":"value1, value2, value3"` is different from `"key":["value1", "value2", "value3"]`

Comment: Sorry, you are right about this, my JSON is exactly how you stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you're looping through your entire json object.
If you want to loop only through key1:

```
for (var i in data.key1) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have jQuery in the tag, I'll point out that you can loop through an object's keys with `each`

```
$.each(data.key1, function(k, v){
    console.log(k, v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the data IS `"value1,value2,value3"`

you need to parse it after that, change your code as such:

```
values=data.key1.split(",");
for(var i in values){
    console.log(i);
}
```